# Is giving money to a foreign government illegal?

Tags: united-states, canada, international

If somebody who was a citizen from one country decided to send a gift to the government/etc. of another country, would that be against the law somehow? Suspicious? Bad for the person?

Say Tom is a Canadian man and he wants to give $1,000,000.00 CAD to the U.S. government as a gift, given for no specific reason. If the monarchy/parliament found out, would he be blacklisted/charged with a crime? Citizenship revoked? Or the same situation with U.S. -> Canada?

I am just wondering since governments tell the citizens of their country that giving gifts (including money) is okay for citizens, but what about for aliens/non-citizens/citizens elsewhere?

No, not made out as bribe/incentive, but just given as a gift -- donation.

Comment: It depends entirely on which countries you're in and a citizen of and donating to.

Comment: Paul Mellon donated money and artwork to state-owned museums around the world: http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2007/03/19/AR2007031901844.html